# Invalid syntax in python 2 creating a simple Naive Bayes classifie

Tags: python

The final step for creating a simple Naive Bayes classifier consists in writing a class `Classifier`, which will use our classes `NBclass` and `Feature`.

```
class Classifier:

    def __init__(self, *nbclasses):
        self.nbclasses = nbclasses


    def prob(self, *d, best_only=True):

        nbclasses = self.nbclasses
        probability_list = []
        for nbclass in nbclasses:            
            ftrs = nbclass.features
            prob = 1
            for i in range(len(ftrs)):
                prob *= nbclass.probability_value_given_feature(d[i], ftrs[i])

            probability_list.append( (prob, nbclass.name) )
        prob_values = [f[0] for f in probability_list]
        prob_sum = sum(prob_values)
        if prob_sum==0:
            number_classes = len(self.nbclasses)
            pl = []
            for prob_element in probability_list:
                pl.append( ((1 / number_classes), prob_element[1]))
            probability_list = pl
        else:
            probability_list = [ (p[0] / prob_sum, p[1])  for p in probability_list]
        if best_only:
            return max(probability_list)
        else:
            return probability_list
```

> // File "", line 7 
>      def prob(self, *d, best_only=True):  
>                                 ^ 
>   **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Note that Python 2 classes do not inherit from object by default, creating old-style classes with a bare ˋclass Classifier:ˋ syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flip `*d` and `best_only=True` and it'll work fine. Python3 allows you to specify keyword-only arguments. Python2 does not, so `*d` expects to accumulate all the rest. Specifying `best_only=True` *after* that makes no sense to the Python2 syntax.

```
class Classifier:

    def __init__(self, *nbclasses):
        self.nbclasses = nbclasses


    def prob(self, best_only=True, *d):

        nbclasses = self.nbclasses
        probability_list = []
        for nbclass in nbclasses:            
            ftrs = nbclass.features
            prob = 1
            for i in range(len(ftrs)):
                prob *= nbclass.probability_value_given_feature(d[i], ftrs[i])

            probability_list.append( (prob, nbclass.name) )
        prob_values = [f[0] for f in probability_list]
        prob_sum = sum(prob_values)
        if prob_sum==0:
            number_classes = len(self.nbclasses)
            pl = []
            for prob_element in probability_list:
                pl.append( ((1 / number_classes), prob_element[1]))
            probability_list = pl
        else:
            probability_list = [ (p[0] / prob_sum, p[1])  for p in probability_list]
        if best_only:
            return max(probability_list)
        else:
            return probability_list
```

Comment: Note though that unlike in Python3, `Classifier().prob(1, 2, 3)` is `best_only=1, d=[2, 3]`, rather than `best_only=True, d=[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: That make my next code crak

TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-11-d7813fd38269> in <module>()
      1 c = Classifier(cls["male"], cls["female"])
      2 for i in range(130, 220, 5):
----> 3     print(i, c.prob(i, best_only=False))

TypeError: prob() got multiple values for keyword argument 'best_only'